# Using AssertSame to validate instance of client from CacheBuilder

Tags: java, unit-testing, guava

Question on CacheBuilder maybe someone can help with:

I have a Cache defined as such:

```
    private final Cache<String, ServiceClient> SERVICE_CLIENT_CACHE = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .maximumSize(1000)
            .build();
```

Accessor logic within the `newRetryingClient` class called from the test

```
        try {
            return SERVICE_CLIENT_CACHE.get(clientConfigQualifier,
                    () -> newClient(clientConfigQualifier));
        } catch (final ExecutionException ignored) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ignored);
        }
    }
```

Attempting to validate the cache is working with a test results in a failure because of different objects...

```
    @Test
    public void newRetryingClientWithMaterials() {
        final clientFactory clientFactory = new clientFactory(authClient, mock(Identity.class));
        final Client client1 = clientFactory.newRetryingClient(QUALIFIER);
        final Client client2 = clientFactory.newRetryingClient(QUALIFIER);
        assertSame(client1, client2);
    }
```

Test Result

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :com.place.thing.client.clientImpl@49d5c751
Actual   :com.place.thing.client.clienttImpl@40e90634
```

any idea if there is an issue with the implementation or I am expecting the wrong behaviors from assertSame?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to test if both objects are referring to the same reference, or do you want to check if they're equal?

See [`assertSame`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.1.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertSame-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) and [`assertEqual`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.1.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertEquals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) but most importantly read about [`Object#equals(Object)][3]` and difference with `==`.